# Remote filtering values are not applied to grid when Nested ajax call is added with existing HttpProxy

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, http-proxy

for Remote filtering ,whenever i click for filter/sort, `Forms.asp` triggers using proxy,and automaticlly reloaded
earlier when i tried below script, to reload the extjs grid with `Forms.asp` returning new xml with filtered grid data, it was working fine.

```
var gridStore = new Ext.data.Store({
            gridId  :'d_grid',
            reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({ record: etc }, etc etc),
            proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({ url: "Forms.asp?", 
            timeout: 120000 }),
            baseParams:{
                XML:$$("XML").value,                                
                some more params                
            },          
            data: doc,
            remoteSort: true});
```

but when i tried to modify it with some WCF call like:

```
var gridStore = new Ext.data.Store({
                gridId  :'d_grid',
                reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({ record: etc }, etc etc),
                proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({ url: "Forms.asp?", 
                timeout: 120000  ,

            success: function (response) {
                FilterXml = response.responseText;

                created new XmlDoc= with somechanges(FilterXml)

                Ext.Ajax.request({
                             method: 'POST',
                             url:'/mayo/Service.svc/GetnewXML',
                             params: {'strIPXML': XmlDoc.xml}});
            }}),
                baseParams:{
                    XML:$$("XML").value,                                
                    some more params                
                },          
                data: doc,
                remoteSort: true});
```

here i am catching the response of earlier asp, and to further modify it sending it to a web service,
with new added ajax returning the same formatted xml as returned in above case (checked using `success: function{ alert etc}`),

but "The new xml is not feeded to the grid , as it was feeding in above case"
no errors are thrown..
using extjs 3.4
please help

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense, can you describe the desired behavior of what you're trying to do?

Comment: trying to do remote filtering i.e store.reload after getting new xml from 'Forms.asp'(earlier), now i have to modify it ,hence using ajax..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after much reading,
Problem was , i thought, ajax will reload data using the `store.load` , used by HttpProxy,after uch reading and hustle i got tht it might not work for ajax, so now i used `store.loaddata` and it worked.

```
var gridStore = new Ext.data.Store({
                gridId  :'d_grid',
                reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({ record: etc }, etc etc),
                proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({ url: "Forms.asp?", 
                timeout: 120000  ,

            success: function (response) {
                FilterXml = response.responseText;

                created new XmlDoc= with somechanges(FilterXml)

                Ext.Ajax.request({
                             method: 'POST',
                             url:'/mayo/Service.svc/GetnewXML',
                             params: {'strIPXML': XmlDoc.xml}

                             success: function (response) {
                                                FormXML = PC.getXmlStr(response.responseXML);
                                                doc = OrchGenericObj.GetXMLObj(FormXML, 0);
                                                Ext.getCmp('dashboard_gd').store.loadData(doc);
                            }    });
            }}),
                baseParams:{
                    XML:$$("XML").value,                                
                    some more params                
                },          
                data: doc,
                remoteSort: true});
```